# SceneKit basics

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am just starting to experiment with SceneKit. Trying a very simple code to create an object, assign physics to it give it a velocity with a tap. So far I was able to create it, apply physics. I was able to give it velocity but could not achieve this with a tap. What am I doing wrong? I am using the same technique I used in SpriteKit but it doesn't work in SceneKit. Please help.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {
let scene = SCNScene()

let shipNode = SCNNode()

let sceneView = SCNScene()

var cameraNode = SCNNode()
var floor = SCNFloor()
var floornod = SCNNode()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sceneView = self.view as SCNView
    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.backgroundColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true


    sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(0, -70, 0)
    sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.speed = 1.0
    sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView.jitteringEnabled = true
    sceneSetup()
    sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode


    let ship = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/sphere.dae")!

    let shipNode = ship.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Sphere", recursively: true)!

    shipNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 50, 300)
    shipNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(10, 10, 10)
    shipNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "ball.jpg")
    shipNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Dynamic, shape: nil)
    shipNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.9
    shipNode.physicsBody?.velocity = SCNVector3Make(0, 100, 10)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shipNode)
    println(shipNode.physicsBody?.velocity.y)
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    shipNode.physicsBody?.velocity = SCNVector3Make(0, 200, 20) // code not working
    println(shipNode.physicsBody?.velocity.y) // prints nil instead of 200.00
}

    func sceneSetup() {

    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.camera?.zNear = 0.01
    cameraNode.camera?.zFar = 800
    cameraNode.camera?.xFov = 45
    cameraNode.camera?.yFov = 75


    cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, -25 * 0.017453293)
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 150, 500)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    floornod.geometry = floor
    floornod.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = "wood1.png"
    floornod.geometry?.firstMaterial?.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
    floornod.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapMode.Repeat
    floornod.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapMode.Repeat
    floornod.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.mipFilter = SCNFilterMode.Linear
    floornod.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static, shape: nil)
    floornod.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(floornod)

}

}
```

The first println gives a result of 100.00.
The println in touchesBegan gives a result of nil every time I tap.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a new local variable in your `viewDidLoad` method with `let shipNode = ...`. This one gets a physics body and gets put into the scene.

This is separate from the instance variable `shipNode` that you defined as part of the class. That one never gets any further configuration, so when you access it in `touchesBegan`, it has no physics body, and optional chaining causes the whole expression for querying its velocity to return nil.

Presumably you want to get rid of the `let`s in `viewDidLoad` so that you're configuring your instance variables instead of shadowing them.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks. It worked!